# Does drinking of Amrit ensure immortality?

Tags: immortality, amrita

Do people who drink Amrit(a)-or drank it in the past- gain *total* immortality?
Does consumption grant freedom from death (that is, cause the drinker never to die), as it did for the Devatas (devas)?

If it does not, what *does* it do. Does it grant temporary relief from death and extend life significantly (perhaps for 100 Brahma years or for one Kalpa), or is it something else?

To summarize: does Amrit grant immortality, or does it 'merely' grant an indefinite, yet significant, increase to the person's lifespan? And if it is the latter, does the increase correspond to the amount drunk?

Comment: immortality is a myth. looooooong life is true. even food that we humans eat is amrit, because by eating it, we are extending our life, and by not eating it we die. same with devas' amrit except it lasts much longer. but that too will run out. how long it lasts is a bit irrelevant, what is relevant is how much punya you have done to stay in svarg lok. even if amrit doesn't run out, but your punya runs out, you get kicked out.

Comment: How about some Tea first to take care of your health : - )?

Answer (score 0):

Drinking Amrita *means* immortality. This is just a poetic way of saying realising the eternal Self or becoming immortal. 'Drinking the cup of immortality' - this is the equivalent of drinking Amrita.

*Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upaniṣad* summarises,

> **4.4.7. When all the desires that dwell in one’s heart are let go, mortal becomes immortal (amṛta) and reaches Brahman.**

The *Khecarīvidyā* provides a more detailed description through a Tantric lens:

> **3.9-11. Between Iḍā and Piṅgalā is the luminous Suṣumnā. There is an undecaying light there, free of the qualities of colour and shape. She who looks like a sleeping serpent is the great Kuṇḍalinī. Gaṅgā and Yamunā are called Iḍā and Piṅgalā. [The yogi] should insert that goddess, in the form of the supreme amṛta, between Gaṅgā and Yamunā, as far as the abode of Brahmā, O goddess. Truly, he becomes identical with Brahmā and automatically gets an immortal body forever.**

Comment: I do not find this an answer. I personally think that amrit gives temporary immortality.

Comment: Both texts say the variation of reaching Brahman or becoming identical with it means immortality. 'Drinking' Amrit refers to the experience of merging with Brahman.